A complex number question
If $|z|+|z -1|=4$ ,then find maximum and minimum  value of $|z -5 i|$ where z denotes a complex number.
Please help me in this question.
I went on like as follow :-
Using triangle inequality,
$||z|-5|| \le |z- 5 i|\le |z| +5$
Since the given equation represent an ellipse on argand plane , we can easily determine that $3/2 ≤ |z| ≤ 5/2$ , using this result max value should be $7.5$ and minimum $2.5$ but I think there is something wrong here .

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Please [edit] the question to tell us what you think is wrong and why?

"There's something wrong here"-- good thought. It's because those bounds might not be attained.

I am just looking for an algebraic proof to this answer with the same ellipse on real Cartesian plane and maximizing its distance from point (0,5)

Always remember that what you've calculated is just a lower and upper bound. For it to be the minimum / maximum, it has to be achieved. You can check the equality cases to verify that it cannot be achieved, so you do not have the min/max value.

Hey @Calvin Line , can you explain how you checked it ?

How would you check it? When would equality occur for you? Can you solve for a $z$ value?

As noticed $|z|+|z -1|=4$ represents an ellipse which equation in cartesian form is
$$15\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+16y^2=60$$
and we need to minimize $|z-5i|$ that is the square root of
$$d^2=x^2+(y-5)^2$$
then by Lagrange multipliers we obtain the system

$x=15\lambda\left(x-\frac12\right)$
$y-5=16\lambda y$
$15\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+16y^2=60$

dividing the first two we obtain
$$\frac x {y-5}=\frac{15}{16} \frac {x-\frac12}y \implies y=\frac{75 (1 - 2 x)}{2x+15}$$
and plugging it in the third equation we obtain
$$2 x^4 + 28 x^3 + 12075 x^2 - 12225 x  + \frac{20625}8=0 $$
which numerically leads to the solution
$$(x,y)\approx (0.299627707291216,1.9267486240542541)$$
such that
$$d=\sqrt{x^2+(y-5)^2}\approx 3.08782298$$
Here another numerical check by WA.


Nice +1. I used the same method but I was too lazy to solve the system and write an answer.

@SineoftheTime Thanks! Did you find the same result?

actually, I just wrote the system (using slightly different equations) but I ended up not solving it

Do it geometrically. $|z|+|z-1|=4$, represents an ellipse with foci at $S'(0,0), S(1,0); 2ae=S'S= 1$ and $2a=4$. The minimum distance between $P(0,5)$ and a point on the ellipse $Q(x',y')$ will occur
when $x'=0$ and $y'$ is such that $|iy'|+|iy'-1|=4 \implies y'=15/8$. So the $$min|z-5i|=min(P,Q)=5-15/8=25/8$$

I've obtained I slightly different result by numerical methods, notably $\min \approx 3.08782298<25/8$. Let me know whether I need to check again. Thanks

Please check again and also post your work. Please also note that @Dharmendra Singh below gets it as 3.0249...

My work is already posted as an answer. Thanks

Dharmendra Singh answer is about a lower bound

How are you claiming that minimum distance occours at $x=0$? this isn’t true just by geometric considerations. Maybe you should revise the answer.

Take a look to this numerical check for more information https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimize+%28x%5E2%2B%28y-5%29%5E2%29%5E.5+when+15%28x-1%2F2%29%5E2%2B16y%5E2%3D60

$$4=|z|+|z-1|\ge |2z-1| \implies 2 \ge |z-1/2|=|z-5i+5i-1/2|$$
$$\ge||z-5i|-\sqrt{\frac{101}{4}}|\implies -2+\sqrt{101/4} \le |z-5i|\le 2+\sqrt{101/4}.$$
Finally, $$|z-5i|\ge \sqrt{101/4}-2=3.02494...$$
